# Flag notification showing continuously in chat when there's no chat flags

Tags: bug, chat, flags, moderator-tools, notifications

The flag notification has been sitting in all the Stack Overflow chat rooms for some hours and there's been no chat flags in that time. The other moderators can also see this.

I went into a chatroom on the Pets site and cannot see a notification.

[image][image]

Comment: Has the issue been fixed yet?

Comment: @EKons yes it has